# Maximum number of redirect URIs in Azure AD B2C for each application?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c

What is the maximum number of redirect urls for a registered application in Azure B2C active Directory? Can I enhance the limitation to 2000 redirect urls for example premium version? I assume the limit of the maximum redirect urls is 256 only.

Comment: **Can I enhance the limitation to 2000 redirect urls for example premium version?**  What does it mean? Do you want to expand the number of redirect URLs?

Comment: @CarlZhao, Yes if it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

The maximum redirect URLs for an app registration is 256.
You can see the limits for redirect URLs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url#maximum-number-of-redirect-uris)

What you can do is Use 1 app registration per instance **Or**  Use a single reply url, and pass a state parameter in the auth request. The state parameter should contain the route to return the user to. The state should be base64 url encoded. After the token comes back to the app, B2C will also return the state parameter sent in the original request. Decode the state and redirect the user to where they started.

Comment: I believe an application registration in an Azure AD B2C tenant has a sign-in audience of "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount" that limits the maximum number of redirect URLs to 100.

Comment: Yes you are right. Based on the account type limit changes as you can see the details provided in the document