# We are using an azure b2c app and that has already reached the redirect URL limits

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Our web application is using Azure b2c and which  has more than 100 different URLs based on the region. Now the limit for azure redirect URL has reached and we can't add new URLS. someone please provide a work around to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no workaround to increase this.
The redirect URL’s Limit for :Personal Microsoft accounts and work and school accounts is 100
AND Microsoft work or school accounts in any organization's Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) tenant is 256.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url)

[Similar Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63406137/maximum-number-of-redirect-uris-in-azure-ad-b2c-for-each-application)